# How to extract and format Median and IQR from a boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, median, extract, quartile

I wish to extract and format the median and interquartile range from my boxplot stat.

I managed to get the raw results with this line of code:

```
b <- boxplot(len ~ dose, data = ToothGrowth)
b$stats
```

Which gives me :

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  4.20 13.60 18.50
[2,]  7.15 16.00 23.45
[3,]  9.85 19.25 25.95
[4,] 13.00 23.45 28.35
[5,] 21.50 27.30 33.90
```

I can exact one row or one column separately adding [,1] or [1,], ie : I can extract min/1st quartile/median/3rd quartile/max for one group OR one stat for each subgroup by example :

```
> b$stats[2,]
[1]  7.15 16.00 23.45
> b$stats[,2]
[1] 13.60 16.00 19.25 23.45 27.30
```

but I can't figure a simple way to extract and format median and IQR for each subgroups [,1] [,2] and [,3] to get something like this :

```
[,1] median [lower quartile-upper quartile].
```

I could do it manually but I have hundreds of variable to save...
Any suggestion would be much appreciated!
Thank by advance

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: If I continue with the Toothgrowth example: [,1] 9.85 [7.15-13.00]  [,2] 19.25 [16.00-23.45]  [,3] 25.95 [23.45-28.35]

Comment: You can use vectors in `[`. So `b$stats[2:4, ]` will give you a matrix of just the lower quartile, median, and upper quartile, for all 3 groups. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Gregor thanks for the proposition. The solution provided by akash87 fits more with my need. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `boxplot`, take a look at `list(b)`, which will provide you with a list of outputs. Now to get median and IQR, that is going to be rows 3 (for median) and 2,4 (for IQR bounds).

```
med <- round(b$stats[3, ], 2) #median
liqr<- round(b$stats[2, ], 2) #lower IQR
uiqr<- round(b$stats[4, ], 2) #upper IQR
```

Now based on your expected output, you will probably want to use some form of `paste` as

```
output <- paste0(med, " [", liqr,"-" ,uiqr,"]")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what i wanted to do ! I added a function to round the output and it is now perfect : `med <- a$stats[3, ] #median
liqr<- a$stats[2, ] #lower IQR
uiqr<- a$stats[4, ] #upper IQR
med <- round(med, 2) 
liqr <- round(liqr, 2)
uiqr <- round(uiqr, 2)
paste0(med, " [", liqr,"-" ,uiqr,"]")`